# disable properties through generic parameters

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Suppose you have a type like:

```
type T<E> = {| p: E |}
```

Is there a way of providing a specific argument for `E` that removes the property `p`.

My intuition was that `void` should be do exactly that but when I try

```
const a: T<void> = {}
```

flow complains that `p` is not defined. It works only when I specifically assign `p`:

```
const b: T<void> = { p: undefined }
```

Is there a way to turn off certain properties this way using flow?

[*try flow* version](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoALgTwA4FMwAqAPAKIB8YAvGAN4A+YuAXGCWHQL6oDGcAdgGd0YAIYtiANzgBLACYVqNLr0HCARuKJS5C2oxYBXPrNxRpfXLLAcgA)

---

This would be helpful if you want to create a generic type alias for redux actions

```
type Action<T: string, P, M> = {|
    type: T,
    payload: P,
    meta: M
|}
```

Where specific actions would have the type

```
type SomeAction = Action<'SOME_ACTION', SomePayload, SomeMeta>
```

It is common for actions to not contain `meta` information though. It would be nice to be able to use the same generic base type for these actions.

```
type NoMetaAction = Action<'NO_META', NoMetaPayload, void>
```

This is something else then `meta` being optional. If a certain action type carries `meta` information than it always carries it and vice versa.

[*try flow* version](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCAxhgJZwB2APACoBcYAzhgE5mUDmANGAAq8AsgD4wAXjABvAD6ow8sNnyNa3OQpwBDLPE0ATRgPXyAtngybGg1NIC+6YMDAIyGABZgzFsByhxWJprkVOhKBADKcGZ82rp64mAADJi4EVF4guaaCclhYJFmJMGUCUUUNADk4QDyggCiAPqEAMK0AJLVAHIVvAV4MTpw+r3pmRbC6qjEVCzM6WVUjH0LJRKSxoqpjFW1jS3tXT0bWoP6jIlqCp5Z56j2qI7Orm5wAK4Y196+-oHFoalgTpwMaaAZxHIpfCA4FZFalUjlagVTrVBr1WiEHrQkFgoZ6XgANzgZD0EymMw+lBhFhWjCBILhaw2YW2KLRdQxRyuJzi50uCi8ljAr0oejwUA4eD0d3Q00osypILqrFY-jp1M0jKkzK2YGRqPRmP58h5eNutiAA)

Comment: No, you'll need to define `T` without "exactness" and with optional `p`: `type T<E> = { p?: E }`

Comment: That would mean that `{}` would be a valid assignment for `T<number>` which I want to prevent.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do? Perhaps on http://flow.org/try ?

Comment: @JamesKraus added examples

Comment: Seems like you'll need to define two types: `type Action<T: string, P> = {| type: T, payload: P |}; type ActionWithMeta<T: string, P, M> = {| ...Action<T,P>, meta: M |};`